# What is required to integrate a Parachain into Kusama?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, rococo

I just integrated our parachain into Rococo. Our testing is completed now we are ready to integrate into Kusama.

I just want to understand what is the process for Kusama integration. Because Rococo and Kusama have different processes.

On Rococo, after registering ParaId, we have to share WASM and state files with community, and they onboard us manually.

I have reserved ParaId on Kusama. My WASM, Spec Json, and Genesis state files are ready. What are the next steps?

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To become a parachain on Kusama, you have to acquire a parachain slot by winning it through a parachain slot auction - https://kusama.network/auctions/

There is also a provision to become a parachain via governance if your blockchain is deemed as a common good parachain.

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains#parachain-slot-acquisition

Answer (score 5):

For both Kusama, there are [slot auctions](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama.api.onfinality.io%2Fpublic-ws#/parachains/auctions), the same happens on Polkadot.

Auction run for a duration and the winner of the auction wins a slot. To win, you either need to have sufficient funds to secure a slot, or use a [crowdloan](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama.api.onfinality.io%2Fpublic-ws#/parachains/crowdloan) where the community backs you.

At the end of the lease period, the locked funds are returned.